# Import excel to tableview (javafx)

Tags: java, excel, javafx

I want a `tableview` to take in values when end user copies data from **excel** and pastes it on the `tableview`..

I want to know the best approach so as of now there isn't any code to post... I want to use `Clipboard` class and manually add content from the clipboard to the table...

- Is that the right approach?
- If not. How to do it?
- Are there any methods or classes which already implement this
  functionality..?

Comment: Rather than implementing this yourself, you might want to look into using a third party library such as [TiwulFX](http://tiwulfx.panemu.com) to do this job.

Comment: @jewelsea the link doesn't work... Anyway, here is another 3rd party solution that you can check out to [import and export Excel to TableView in JavaFX](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet-java/examples/javafx-import-export-excel-tableview/5301)

Comment: Mario, both the he tiwulfx llink I posted and the gembox link you posted work fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this. But you need to adapt the code to match your requirements (e. g. numberformatting, etc).

TableCopyPasteCellsDemo.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableCopyPasteCellsDemo extends Application {

    private final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Person("Jacob", "Smith", 18), new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", 19), new Person("Ethan", "Williams", 20), new Person("Michael", "Brown", 21));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(550);

        // create table columns
        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

        TableColumn<Person, Integer> ageCol = new TableColumn<Person, Integer>("Age");
        ageCol.setMinWidth(60);
        ageCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Integer>("age"));


        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setPlaceholder(new Text("No content in table"));
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, ageCol);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(table);

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(borderPane);

        vbox.getChildren().add( new Label( "Select cells and press CTRL+C. Paste the data into Excel or Notepad"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // enable multi-selection
        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        // enable copy/paste
        TableUtils.installCopyPasteHandler(table);
    }


    public static class Person {

        private final StringProperty firstName;
        private final StringProperty lastName;
        private final IntegerProperty age;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, Integer age) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFirstName(final java.lang.String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLastName(final java.lang.String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }

        public final IntegerProperty ageProperty() {
            return this.age;
        }

        public final int getAge() {
            return this.ageProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setAge(final int age) {
            this.ageProperty().set(age);
        }

    }


}
```

TableUtils.java

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class TableUtils {

    private static NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();


    /**
     * Install the keyboard handler:
     *   + CTRL + C = copy to clipboard
     *   + CTRL + V = paste to clipboard
     * @param table
     */
    public static void installCopyPasteHandler(TableView<?> table) {

        // install copy/paste keyboard handler
        table.setOnKeyPressed(new TableKeyEventHandler());

    }

    /**
     * Copy/Paste keyboard event handler.
     * The handler uses the keyEvent's source for the clipboard data. The source must be of type TableView.
     */
    public static class TableKeyEventHandler implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

        KeyCodeCombination copyKeyCodeCompination = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.C, KeyCombination.CONTROL_ANY);
        KeyCodeCombination pasteKeyCodeCompination = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.V, KeyCombination.CONTROL_ANY);

        public void handle(final KeyEvent keyEvent) {

            if (copyKeyCodeCompination.match(keyEvent)) {

                if( keyEvent.getSource() instanceof TableView) {

                    // copy to clipboard
                    copySelectionToClipboard( (TableView<?>) keyEvent.getSource());

                    // event is handled, consume it
                    keyEvent.consume();

                }

            } 
            else if (pasteKeyCodeCompination.match(keyEvent)) {

                if( keyEvent.getSource() instanceof TableView) {

                    // copy to clipboard
                    pasteFromClipboard( (TableView<?>) keyEvent.getSource());

                    // event is handled, consume it
                    keyEvent.consume();

                }

            } 

        }

    }

    /**
     * Get table selection and copy it to the clipboard.
     * @param table
     */
    public static void copySelectionToClipboard(TableView<?> table) {

        StringBuilder clipboardString = new StringBuilder();

        ObservableList<TablePosition> positionList = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();

        int prevRow = -1;

        for (TablePosition position : positionList) {

            int row = position.getRow();
            int col = position.getColumn();

            // determine whether we advance in a row (tab) or a column
            // (newline).
            if (prevRow == row) {

                clipboardString.append('\t');

            } else if (prevRow != -1) {

                clipboardString.append('\n');

            }

            // create string from cell
            String text = "";

            Object observableValue = (Object) table.getColumns().get(col).getCellObservableValue( row);

            // null-check: provide empty string for nulls
            if (observableValue == null) {
                text = "";
            }
            else if( observableValue instanceof DoubleProperty) { // TODO: handle boolean etc

                text = numberFormatter.format( ((DoubleProperty) observableValue).get());

            }
            else if( observableValue instanceof IntegerProperty) { 

                text = numberFormatter.format( ((IntegerProperty) observableValue).get());

            }                   
            else if( observableValue instanceof StringProperty) { 

                text = ((StringProperty) observableValue).get();

            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Unsupported observable value: " + observableValue);
            }

            // add new item to clipboard
            clipboardString.append(text);

            // remember previous
            prevRow = row;
        }

        // create clipboard content
        final ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
        clipboardContent.putString(clipboardString.toString());

        // set clipboard content
        Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().setContent(clipboardContent);


    }

    public static void pasteFromClipboard( TableView<?> table) {

        // abort if there's not cell selected to start with
        if( table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // get the cell position to start with
        TablePosition pasteCellPosition = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0);

        System.out.println("Pasting into cell " + pasteCellPosition);

        String pasteString = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getString();

        System.out.println(pasteString);

        int rowClipboard = -1;

        StringTokenizer rowTokenizer = new StringTokenizer( pasteString, "\n");
        while( rowTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {

            rowClipboard++;

            String rowString = rowTokenizer.nextToken();

            StringTokenizer columnTokenizer = new StringTokenizer( rowString, "\t");

            int colClipboard = -1;

            while( columnTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {

                colClipboard++;

                // get next cell data from clipboard
                String clipboardCellContent = columnTokenizer.nextToken();

                // calculate the position in the table cell
                int rowTable = pasteCellPosition.getRow() + rowClipboard;
                int colTable = pasteCellPosition.getColumn() + colClipboard;

                // skip if we reached the end of the table
                if( rowTable >= table.getItems().size()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if( colTable >= table.getColumns().size()) {
                    continue;
                }

                // System.out.println( rowClipboard + "/" + colClipboard + ": " + cell);

                // get cell
                TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumns().get(colTable);
                ObservableValue observableValue = tableColumn.getCellObservableValue(rowTable);

                System.out.println( rowTable + "/" + colTable + ": " +observableValue);

                // TODO: handle boolean, etc
                if( observableValue instanceof DoubleProperty) { 

                    try {

                        double value = numberFormatter.parse(clipboardCellContent).doubleValue();
                        ((DoubleProperty) observableValue).set(value);

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                else if( observableValue instanceof IntegerProperty) { 

                    try {

                        int value = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(clipboardCellContent).intValue();
                        ((IntegerProperty) observableValue).set(value);

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }                   
                else if( observableValue instanceof StringProperty) { 

                    ((StringProperty) observableValue).set(clipboardCellContent);

                } else {

                    System.out.println("Unsupported observable value: " + observableValue);

                }

                System.out.println(rowTable + "/" + colTable);
            }

        }

    }

}
```